# I am missing the Relationships Field Type

Tags: fieldtype, fields

This is simply my problem, I have no relationships field. I have no idea how I would've removed this and or how that would even be possible considering it's a native EE function.

Any clue how to get this back?

Comment: If you go to Add-Ons > Fieldtypes, does Relationships show as Installed?

Comment: Oh boy, early friday morning is not my best friend. Haha. As soon as I saw your comment I knew the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Relationships fieldtype installed. Go to Add-Ons > Fieldtypes, check if  Relationships shows as Installed. (moved to answer from comments)